# Refresh picklist data on page refresh in jsf 1.2

Tags: jsf, jsf-1.2

I have a picklist on my jsf page, My requirement is for data on left side to clear and go back to default state on page refresh. However, the jsf page retains state after refresh.

```
<h:panelGrid>
<rich:pickList sourceListWidth="200" targetListWidth="200" value="#{Bean.slctdVals}">
<f:selectItems value="#{Bean.allVals}" />
</rich:pickList>
</h:panelGrid>
```

Comment: You are using RichFaces here dou you know that?

Comment: @Kukeltje Yes, but how does that affect the refresh functionality?

Comment: Bean.allVals <- this bean needs to be Requestscoped or Viewscoped, else it will still hold the values after a refresh

Comment: I have this in my faces-config: 
<managed-bean>
  <managed-bean-name>Bean</managed-bean-name>
  <managed-bean-class>com.jsf.bean.Bean</managed-bean-class>
  <managed-bean-scope>request</managed-bean-scope>
 </managed-bean>

Comment: No idea, but no idea why it should not. Could be an issue in the RichFaces picklist. And if it is JSF, there must be other code like that is waaay more relevant than this. Like @theMahaloRecords stated.